# Python - How to define attributes not affected by __getattr__?

Tags: python, xml, ironpython, getattr

I'm fairly new to Python.  In programming a lot of PHP recently I got used to some creative use of `__get` and `__set` "magic" methods.  These were only called when a public variable of the class wasn't present.

I'm trying to replicate the same behavior in Python, but seem to be failing miserably.  Given there doesn't seem to be a way to actually define class variables in a C++/PHP way, when I try to use variables normally within my class (i.e. via self) it ends up calling `__getattr__`!

**How do I define attributes of my class that I don't want affected by `__getattr__`?**

Some sample code of what I'm trying to do is below, where I'd want `self.Document` and `self.Filename` NOT to invoke `__getattr__`.

Thanks for the help!

```
class ApplicationSettings(object):
    RootXml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Settings></Settings>'

    def __init__(self):
        self.Document = XmlDocument()
        self.Document.LoadXml(RootXml)

    def Load(self, filename):
        self.Filename = filename
        self.Document.Load(filename)

    def Save(self, **kwargs):
        # Check if the filename property is present
        if 'filename' in kwargs:
            self.Filename = kwargs['filename']

        self.Document.Save(self.Filename)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.Document.Item['Settings'][attr].InnerText

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr in self.Document.Item['Settings']:
            # If the setting is already in the XML tree then simply change its value
            self.Document.Item['Settings'][attr].InnerText = value
        else:
            # Setting is not in the XML tree, create a new element and add it
            element = self.Document.CreateElement(attr)
            element.InnerText = value

            self.Document.Item['Settings'].AppendChild(element)
```

Comment: If the attribute is found by the normal lookup process, `__getattr__` should not be called.

Comment: Don't put the answer into the question, post it as an answer. Then, after two days, accept it.

Comment: `object.__setattr__` isn't quite as "hoaky" as it seems - thing about it this way: if you hadn't overridden `__setattr__` yourself, `object.__setattr__` is the function that would actually get called, so in reality you're doing what happens a lot in subclassing - calling the superclass's implementation for all invocations you don't want to overide in the subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if I check for the attribute name in `__setattr__` I can then call object's `__setattr__` for the attributes I want to use normally.  This feels pretty hoaky, but works.

```
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        # Check for attributes we want to store normally
        if attr == 'Document' or attr == 'Filename':
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        # If the setting is already in the XML tree then simply change its value
        elif attr in self.Document.Item['Settings']:
            self.Document.Item['Settings'][attr].InnerText = value
        # Setting is not in the XML tree, create a new element and add it
        else:
            element = self.Document.CreateElement(attr)
            element.InnerText = value

            self.Document.Item['Settings'].AppendChild(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

`__getattr__` is only invoked when Python cannot find the attribute in the instance itself or in any of its base classes.  The simple solution is to add `Document` and `Filename` to the class so it is found.

```
class ApplicationSettings(object):
    Document = None
    Filename = None
    RootXml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Settings></Settings>'
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really need here is a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html). Hooking `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` like that is not really recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property). Using the `@property` decorator makes it looks even nicer.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

You can then access `C.x` and it will automatically call the getter for x, and automatically call the setter for x when you assign to `C.x`.